The functional equation $f(x^2+f(y))+f(y^2)=2x^2y$
I have a functional equation problem:
$f(x^2+f(y))+f(y^2)=2x^2y$
I have attempted many things but here was the furthest I have gotten:
Substitute $x=0$:
$f(f(y))+f(y^2)=0$
Substitute $y=0$:
$f(x^2+f(0))+f(0)=0$
Since this is symmetrical, we have:
$f(y^2+f(0))+f(0)=f(f(y))+f(y^2)$
I don't know where to go from here, can I get some help? Thank you.

There are no solutions to $f$.
If we substitute $y=0$ we yield
$$f(x^2+f(0))+f(0)=0$$
Thus, for all $x \geq f(0)$, we have $f(x) = c$.
Now, if $f(0) \neq 0$, we substitute $y=f(0)$ to yield
$$f(x^2)+f(0)=2x^2f(0) \Rightarrow f(x) = c(2x-1)$$
for $x \geq 0$.
So now, we can substitute $y=0$ to get $2c=0$ and thus $f(x)=0$.
Otherwise, $f(0)=0$. Now, we have $f(x)=0$ for all $x \geq 0$.
Thus, we have
$$f(x^2+f(y))=2x^2y$$
FTSOC, let there exist a $y<0$ such that $f(y) < 0$.
Now, if $f(y) < 0$, we can substitute $x=\sqrt{-f(y)}$ and so we yield
$$2y\sqrt{-f(y)} = 0$$
Since $y \neq 0$, we must have that $f(y) = 0$ and this is a contradiction.
Now, if $f(y) > 0$, we can substitute $x=1$ to obtain $0=2y$ which is a contradiction.
So now, we have $f(x)=0$. However, subbing this back this function does not work.
Thus, there are no solutions to this functional equation.

Let $P(x,y)$ be the claim $f(x^2+f(y))+f(y^2)=2x^2y$.
From $P(0,x)$ we get $f(x^2)=-f(f(x))$, while $P(1,x)$ gives $f(1+f(x))+f(x^2)=2x$. Combining together we get
$$
f(1+f(x))-f(f(x))=2x.\tag{*}
$$
Now if $f(a)=f(b)$ then $(*)$ implies $a=b$, i.e. $f$ is injective.
Also for $x=0$ the $(*)$ gives $f(1+f(0))=f(f(0))$, hence by injectivity $1+f(0)=f(0)$, impossible. So there is no solution.

Let $P(x, y)$ be the assertion.
$P(0, 0) \implies f(f(0)) + f(0) = 0$
$P(x, 0) \implies f(x^2 + f(0)) + f(0) = 0$
So $$f(f(0)) = f(x^2 + f(0))$$
Which means that for sufficently large $x$, $f$ is constant. Thus, we may write
$$f \equiv c$$
for some real constant $c$ for all $x \ge N$.
But then picking large enough $x$ and $y$ means that $f(x^2 + f(y)) + f(y^2)$ is constant, which is a contradiction because it means $2x^2y$ must be constant. Thus no such function $f$ exists.
